# CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824) NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, ios9

I am sending a post request using the following code in iOS 9 to a https server

```
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&requestResponse error:&err];
```

But I get the following error

```
CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824)
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)
```

I have tried adding the exception to info.plist as follows:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
    <key>www.myserver.com</key>
    <dict>
    <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
    <string>TLSv1.1</string>
</dict>
```

I also tried

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
   <dict>
     <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
     <true/>
   </dict>
```

It works on a real device but not on a simulator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. > From NSURLConnection to NSURLSession worked for me

I was able to solve as following( NSURLConnection is deprecated and you need to use NSURLSession) :

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                    completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData  *data, NSError *error) {
 // ... 
}];
```

converted to:

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                     completionHandler:
 ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
     // ...
  }];

[task resume];
```

[From NSURLConnection to NSURLSession](https://www.objc.io/issues/5-ios7/from-nsurlconnection-to-nsurlsession/)

2. Also included in Info.plist see documentation:

[Info.plist reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33)

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
  <key>yourdomain.net</key>
  <dict>
  <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
  <true/>
  <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
  <true/>
  <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
  <string>1.2</string>
  <key>NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
  <false/>
  </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

3. And ultimately

> Announcement: CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824) while integrating Login with Amazon SDK for iOS
>   Back to Category    Back to Category

[CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824) while integrating Login with Amazon SDK for iOS
Back to Category    Back to Category](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/ann.jspa?annID=322)

Just change to yourdomain.net from api.amazon.com

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Doing following solved my issue:

1. Add/Edit in info.plist

`<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
      <dict>
      <key>yourdomain.com</key>
      <dict>
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>1.2</string>
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
      <false/>
      </dict>
      </dict>
    </dict>`

2. Add following code in your class which delegates NSURLConnection

`- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpac
{
    return YES;
}`

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    NSArray *trustedHosts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"mytrustedhost",nil];

    if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]){
        if ([trustedHosts containsObject:challenge.protectionSpace.host]) {
            [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        }
    }
    [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

Hope this will help you.